# Create a background gradient based on image data

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, lazy-loading, linear-gradients

I have made a graceful image loader with bootstrap card, which displays a gradient fill in the background whilst the image is loading. Once the image loads it fades in. The gradient colours were manually created based on some of the key colours from the image.

Does anybody know of a JS module, or something similar, which can read the color data of an image before an image is loaded in to the HTML? Because I would love to create the gradient colors dynamically based on the image that is being loaded in. I'm pretty sure PHP can do it somehow, but if JS can do it then it's easier to handle. I know it's a long shot.

You can see it working (with manually entered gradients) in the codepen link below:

https://codepen.io/jtibbles/pen/LYydBOx

HTML:

```
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;vertical-align:top;">
  <div class="card-img-container cardgradient1">
  <div class="card-img-top cardimage" data-src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/5cd6ef_0b75bcb5a2cbf17a53e97f76659cf189.jpg/v1/fill/w_503,h_335,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/5cd6ef_0b75bcb5a2cbf17a53e97f76659cf189.webp">    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
  <p class="card-text">This card displays a nice gradient in the image location until the image is loaded in to place. The image then fades in gracefully.</p>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="examplebtn">reload...</a>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;vertical-align:top;">
  <div class="card-img-container cardgradient2">
  <div class="card-img-top cardimage " data-src="https://d3iso9mq9tb10q.cloudfront.net/wysiwyg/sanfrancisco/01-city-landing/San-Francisco-Skyline-Golden-Gate-Bridge-Big-Bus-Tours-Jan-2016.jpg"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
  <p class="card-text">This card displays a nice gradient in the image location until the image is loaded in to place. The image then fades in gracefully.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card-img-container{
border-top-left-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px);
border-top-right-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px);
width:100%;
display:block;
height:190px;
position:relative;
}
.card-img-container .cardimage{ 
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  opacity:0;
  transition:opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
.card-img-container .cardimage.show{
  opacity:1;
}
.card-img-container .cardimage.notransition{
  transition:none;
}

.card-img-container.cardgradient1{
    background: rgb(222,200,200);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(222,200,200,0.6) 0%, 
    rgba(162,140,120,0.6) 31%, rgba(153,201,189,0.6) 65%, rgba(153,122,72,0.6) 85%);
}

.card-img-container.cardgradient2{
  background: rgb(227,255,253);
  background: linear-gradient(175deg, rgba(227,255,253,0.6) 1%, rgba(255,234,227,0.6) 15%, rgba(199,61,27,0.6) 44%, rgba(76,106,180,0.6) 92%);
}
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

gracefulImageLoader();

//Just for purposes of this demo
document.getElementById("examplebtn").addEventListener("click",function(){
    resetDemo();  //Just for purposes of this demo
    window.setTimeout(gracefulImageLoader,2000);
});

function gracefulImageLoader(){
  var cardimages = document.getElementsByClassName("cardimage");
  for (let i = 0; i < cardimages.length; i++) {
    let currentcardimage = cardimages[i];      
    if(currentcardimage.dataset !=""){
      let img = new Image();
      img.src = currentcardimage.dataset.src;
      img.onload = function () {
        currentcardimage.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+img.src+"')";
        currentcardimage.classList.add("show");
      }
    }  
  }  
}   

function resetDemo(){
   let cardimages = document.getElementsByClassName("cardimage");
   for (let i = 0; i < cardimages.length; i++) {
     let currentcardimage = cardimages[i];
     currentcardimage.classList.add("notransition");
     currentcardimage.classList.remove("show");
     currentcardimage.style.backgroundImage = "none";
     window.setTimeout(function()    {currentcardimage.classList.remove("notransition");},250);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hum... interesting... There is some js lib like [vibrant.js](http://jariz.github.io/vibrant.js/) or [color-thief](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief) but they are aways working on loaded images (which make sens because it's on front-side)...

A workaroud could be to create a very-low res image which will be loaded with html, then your JS will create the gradient, and then lazy-load the real image...?

Another solution could be to use a server-side solution like [color-extractor](https://github.com/thephpleague/color-extractor) which is a php solution, and then create your gradient directly with inline-css on your dom element

Comment: Thanks. Color-extractor was the option I was thinking of if I'm using a server-side solution. This is fine for my custom websites (I can just build it in to the uploader), but for third party cms systems I would have to develop plugins to run after an image is loaded in to whatever the media gallery is. But it might be worth it. I thought I could even include the gradient data within the name of the file, like image_hxcolor1-percentage1_hxcolor2-percentage2_hxcolor3-percentage3